# Dynamically updating select-elements depending on user selection

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, select

I'm working on a project (using Laravel 5.4), and in this project I have a form. The form consists of 4 different select-elements. Each time a selection is updated, the select-elements below it have to be updated with option-entries that are suitable depending on the previous selections.

So far, AJAX seems to be necessary since the options in each select-element are retrieved from a database. It might also be worth mentioning that there could potentially be **over 10 options** for each previous option.

**My question is**: Would it be most efficient to build a JSON API that handles these AJAX-requests (using previous selections as "filters"), *or* more efficient to load all the options for all the select-elements first and then update the select-elements options through JavaScript?

*Question in short*: Dynamically loading the options or dynamically adding/removing the options (pre-loaded)?

Or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: It depends on the quantity. If you have hundreds or thousands of options in total, obviously Ajax is the way to go. Otherwise, if you have like 30-50 options, loading them all at once would be ok. If you expect this number to grow over time, prefer the Ajax approach, to make it future-proof.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly the kind of response I needed. The total number of options would almost reach a thousand, so I'll be using AJAX.